# Date increment in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to increment date in js, its working but time getting as the current date. is there any way to get a new time with increment.

```
   new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));
```

Output: `Fri Oct 26 2018 17:43:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I want like: `Fri Oct 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: Do you want to make time 0?

Comment: Just use js-joda :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Date.setHours(hour,min,sec,millisec)
```

is the function you are after.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the `time` of your `date`.

You can use `.setHours(0,0,0,0)`:

```
let d = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Take a look at [`Date.prototype.setHours()` **MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) for further details.

**Demo:**

```js
let d = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
document.write(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting its hours,minutes,seconds and milliseconds properties:

```
const myDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));
myDate.setHours(0);
myDate.setMinutes(0);
myDate.setSeconds(0);
myDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```

or use the just setHours with more parameters to do it at once:

```
const myDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));
myDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```